# how to skip a command or line of code during a debugging session

Tags: r, debugging

while debugging in the R language, is it possible to bypass the `stop()` and make it to the code that i want to step through?

```
myfun <-
    function(){
        browser()
        stop("any way around this?")

        print("code that i want to step through")

        TRUE
    }

myfun()
```

Comment: put `browser()` after `stop` line ?

Comment: @RonakShah That would mean changing the logic of the source code, which then might defeat the purpose of debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask `stop`:

```
> myfun()
Called from: myfun()
Browse[1]> stop <- message
Browse[1]> n
debug at #4: stop("any way around this?")
Browse[2]> n
any way around this?
debug at #6: print("code that i want to step through")
Browse[2]> stop <- base::stop
Browse[2]> n
[1] "code that i want to step through"
debug at #8: [1] TRUE
Browse[2]> n
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the archived `debug` package. It contains a skip function you can use while debugging, though you are using another debug function then.

```
#devtools::install_version("debug",version="1.3.1")

library(debug)

mtrace(myfun)


myfun <-
  function(){
    print(1)
    stop("any way around this?")
    print(2)
    print("code that i want to step through")

    TRUE
  }

myfun()
```

you can use then the debugger in console with `skip()`. For introduction of the debug package, check the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/debug/versions/1.3.1/topics/debug-package)